# AddView() to Expandable ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, expandablelistview

i got a Expandable ListView. I Need to integrate dynamically View(Relative layout with textview) into ListView.
I have an axml file(it's like template for my dynamic views).
I'm doing like this

```
View _view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DynamicControl,null);
```

After that,i'm trying to put into Expandable list(called "_List") :

```
_List.AddView(_view,0); //where 0 is position(index)
```

Than i use adapter,to put into ListView data :

```
_List.SetAdapter(new _Adapter(this, List<MyClass>, _List));
```

IDE give me exception :

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not
>   supported in AdapterView

I read that,`AddView()` doesnt integrate in listView views and i need to use(always) adapter. Is that true?(Maybe exist workaround or i can override my constructor(Of Custom _Adapter) and give another parametrs,like Context and Views?).
By the way,why `AddFooterView / AddHeaderView` work properly ?

PS Sorry for my eng. Thanks!

UPD :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LhLA.png

```
"My New View" - // Row for Expandable ListView,which is RelativeLayout(into this Layout i got TextView).
```

How can i do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workaround was(for me),to generate post condition and put different layouts :

```
var inflater = _context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as  LayoutInflater;

  if(!SpecificLayout)
    {
      view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SpecificLayout, null);
    }
  else
    {
      view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AnotherLayout, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> addView() not supported in AdapterView.
>   Blockquote

Which means AdapterView - >
ListView, ExpandableListView, ViewPager ... etc.

I don`t know what to do do exactly. 
Show me mockup, or any picture of UI. Then may i help you.

Comment: I added comment(mockup),can you say something?
BTW why for AddHeader/Footer View its ok,works properly,but for other AddView,doesnt? Where is the logic :|

Comment: First of all declare your adapter and it`s data globally. In this case 
List<MyClass> myDatas = new ArrayList<>();
... add some data to your myDatas
_Adapter myAdapter = new _Adapter(... ,  myDatas, ...);
...
_List.setAdapter(myAdapter);
Then if you want to add row :
myDatas.add(yourIndex, new MyClass(...));
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: thanks mate! I maked my workaround(different layouts for view on GroupView with specific condition),but your idea is awesome. i Will test latter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can only add view to a list view with the help of an adapter.For adding a custom view we need to define our own adapter by extending one of the adapter class like **BaseAdapter**, **CursorAdapter** etc.

for example : we have

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private List<String> name;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ContactListAdapter(Activity activity) {
        layoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        name = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addMessage(String message) {
        name.add(message);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void removeMessage(String message) {
        name.remove(message);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return name.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int i) {
         return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int direction = getItemViewType(i);


                 if (convertView == null) {

            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list, viewGroup, false);
        }

        String message = name.get(i);



        final TextView txtMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        txtMessage.setText(message.toString());

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactImage);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

this adapter add a contact list view having one image and one TextView.
Add header and footer view is just to define the header and footer part which is fix and nothing to to with list view which have all same type of view header and footer can be diffrent.